# How do you make a product older and remove it from latest products?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How do you make a product older.

I have a list of products that show up in the latest products after a product import after migrating to magento 2.

I would like to make some products show in the latest products slider.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option in magento 2 admins product page 'Set Product as New From'.

[image]